# Sequelize TypeScript Error: Property 'course_temp' does not exist on type 'User'

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm working on a Node.js project using Sequelize with TypeScript, and I've set up associations between my models. However, I'm encountering an issue where TypeScript is giving me an error indicating that properties like 'course_temp' and 'profile' do not exist on the 'User' type, even though I've defined these associations in my Sequelize models.

this is the function code

```
import { CourseTemp } from '../models/CourseTemp';
import { User } from '../models/User';
import { Profile } from '../models/Profile';
import { CourseGeneration } from '../models/CourseGeneration';

const requestbody = await User.findOne({
                        attributes: ['username', 'giga_access_token'],
                        where: {
                            user_id: user_id
                        },
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: Profile,
                                as: 'profile',
                                attributes: ['fname', 'lname'],
                            },
                            {
                                model: CourseTemp,
                                as: 'course_temp',
                                where: {
                                    course_temp_id: course_temp_id,
                                    user_id: user_id
                                },
                                attributes: ['confirm_date'],
                                include: [
                                    {
                                        model: CourseGeneration,
                                        where: {
                                            course_generation_id: CourseTempChk.course_generation_id
                                        },
                                        as: 'course_generation',
                                        attributes: ['date_end'],
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                    }
                 );
```

I've defined the associations in models. this is User

```
import { UUIDV4 } from 'sequelize'
import { Model, DataTypes, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes, CreationOptional } from 'sequelize'
import { sequelize } from '../Database'
import { Profile } from './Profile'; 
import { CourseTemp } from './CourseTemp';

export class User extends Model<InferAttributes<User>, InferCreationAttributes<User>> {...
}
User.init(
    {
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            defaultValue: UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        .
        . //rest of the code
        .
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'user'
    }
)
```

And this is Profile and CourseTemp model

```
import { Model, DataTypes, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes, CreationOptional } from 'sequelize'
import { sequelize } from '../Database'
import { User } from './User'

export class CourseTemp extends Model<InferAttributes<CourseTemp>, InferCreationAttributes<CourseTemp>> {...
}
CourseTemp.init(
    {...
})
CourseTemp.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id',
    targetKey: 'user_id',
    as: 'User',
  })
User.hasMany(CourseTemp, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id',
    sourceKey: 'user_id',
    as: 'CourseTemp',
  })
```

```
import { Model, DataTypes, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes, CreationOptional } from 'sequelize'
import { sequelize } from '../Database'
import { User } from './User'

export class Profile extends Model<InferAttributes<Profile>, InferCreationAttributes<Profile>> {...
}

Profile.init(
    {...
})
Profile.belongsTo(
    User,
    {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        targetKey: 'user_id',
        as: 'User'
    }
)
User.hasOne(
    Profile,
    {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        sourceKey: 'user_id',
        as: 'Profile'
    }
)
```

This worked fine when the project was in JS, but now I'm encountering these issues after transitioning to TS. Its erroring on building process

```
/course.ts:76:57 - error TS2339: Property 'course_temp' does not exist on type 'User'.

76                         const confirmDate = requestbody.course_temp[0].confirm_date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~

/course.ts:77:53 - error TS2339: Property 'course_temp' does not exist on type 'User'.

77                         const dateEnd = requestbody.course_temp[0].course_generation[0].date_end.toISOString().split('T')[0];
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~

/course.ts:81:52 - error TS2339: Property 'profile' does not exist on type 'User'.

81                             FirstName: requestbody.profile.fname,
                                                      ~~~~~~~

/course.ts:82:51 - error TS2339: Property 'profile' does not exist on type 'User'.

82                             LastName: requestbody.profile.lname,
```